# How to recover Hybrid Remote app from Bootstrap Error? (iOS)

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, hybrid-remote, salesforce-sdk-hybrid

When an iOS Hybrid Remote app built using the Salesforce Mobile SDK launches, if it cannot connect to the network, it will generate a "Bootstrap Error Page" like the one below:

[image: Bootstrap Error]

Although it doesn't seem to be documented, looking at `SFHybridViewController.m` in the MobileSDK source reveals that you can override this generic error page by suppling an `error.html` page in your app's `www` folder.  The SDK will even pass the error code, description, and context as URL params.

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to recover, short of killing the running app using the task switcher and restarting the app.  The error page gets loaded into its own UIWebView, and I don't see how to allow the user to recover from that point.

I could provide a link on the error page, or even use the cordova `network-information` plugin to detect when the app is online again, and auto-navigate, but I don't know where to navigate... probably my app's start page URL, but I think I'll have to hardcode that into the error page, as I see no way to fetch it.  I'm also unclear if this will work correctly with auth, given that the error page is loaded into its own UIWebView (and that's about the extent of my understanding of the native code layer).  Is there a support way to recover from bootstrap errors?